# Picasso requests with respect to success and error count does not match

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-volley, picasso

Below is sample code. The number of times the Picasso gets called is more than the number of times it reaches Success or OnError().  How can I deal with the ProgressBar in this situation?   This happens , since i am invoking this method from the ArrayAdapter.

How can I get and print the reason for OnError in picasso loading.

```
/**
 * To get the Customized Picasso with preset placeholders, CallBack for progressBar, sqSize on req
 */
public static Picasso getAuthorizedPicasso(final ImageView imgView, final String url, final int sqSize) {

    EventBus.post(ToggleProgressBar.requestStarted());
    final Picasso picasso = CustomPicasso.getInstance();

    picasso.load(url)
            .resize(sqSize, sqSize)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).noFade().into(imgView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            EventBus.post(ToggleProgressBar.requestFinished());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            EventBus.post(ToggleProgressBar.requestFinished());
        }
    });

    return picasso;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The ListView ArrayAdapter gets called often. Hence updated the ListView with match_parent or fill_parent avoids calling the Picasso multiple times. This solved the infinitely running ProgressBar with Picasso issue as well.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

PS: Please voteup if you find this helpful.Thanks